# knockout template name dynamically taken from observable array item property value

Tags: knockout.js

I am new to “knockout”, so please be patient.
I have an observable array that consists of objects where one of the properties (“template type”) holds a name of a template to be used.  How can I dynamically assign the property value (template type) while iterating through the observable array in HTML?

```
//Short version of an array object (‘containerData’ is read from MVC)
function smContainerViewModel(containerData) {
            var self = this;
            self.id = ko.observable(containerData.id);                
            self.templateType = ko.observable(containerData.containerType);
        }; 
//viewModel
function AppViewModel(dataInput) {          
            var self = this;
            self.koContainersArray = ko.observableArray();
            for (var i = 0; i < dataInput.containersArray.length; i++) {
                self.koContainersArray.push(new smContainerViewModel(dataInput.containersArray[i]));
            };

            self.currentTemplate = ko.computed(function () {
//Currently I can return the below static name of a template. I would like to return: 
//  koContainersArray()[index]. templateType;
                 return 'template1';                  
            });               
     };  

     var viewModelSM = new AppViewModel(initialData);          
     ko.applyBindings(viewModelSM);

//HTML 
<div data-bind="template:{name:currentTemplate ,foreach:koContainersArray}"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.

```
<!-- ko foreach: koContainersArray -->
<div data-bind="template: templateType"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

This would work as long as whatever is set as `templateType` is template1 or whatever the Id of the template is.

Here is an example fiddle -

http://jsfiddle.net/pwkad/eo4ft2z0/

Comment: Could you please, show me the full loop “foreach” syntax?

Comment: @j23 I added an example fiddle

Comment: Sorry. it does not work. What I meant was "How should I iterate through" the array. => <div data-bind="foreach:koContainersArray">                          
<div data-bind="template: templateType">/div>                             
</div>

Comment: I must be missing what you are looking for - if you look at the fiddle I have an array in the view model that is passed to the view, and then the foreach iterates over each item and shows the associated template type, which is set in the array.  That is why you see three templates showing but you could easily add more.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It started to work. There were some initial data (sent from DB) interpretation problems. I will test each template as these are moveable/resizable containers for different media. At the moment, after binding I lost drag and resize limits or having limits they shrink to 0 height. In the meantime, could you please, refer me to the documentation for the looping syntax you used.

Comment: All problems solved. Thank you. But there are new ones. Do you know how to embed the video or media file (Wolfram CDF) into the knockout template where mediaFileName is an observable variable? <script id="smVideo" type="text/html">
            <video data-bind="src: mediaFileName" width="300" height="200" controls />
     </script>
At this stage I noticed that even a hard coded filePath+filename  (src=”~/filelocation/filename”) does not work inside script tag. I have message “Video format or MIME type is not supported”.

Comment: @j23 Seems like a completely separate issue - can you open a new question on this?  It will get more views that way as well so more help probably.